# Problem compiling Bibliography on Gummi

Tags: bibtex, gummi

I am trying to create cites and bibliography,in ApJ style, using the tex commands below using Gummi.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ natbib}
\citestyle{aa}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\cite{texbook}

\section{Conclusion} 

\cite{Narendra_1990}

\bibliography{Bib2}{}
\bibliographystyle{apj}

\end{document}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
/tmp/.LatexEssay.tex.bbl:8: Undefined control sequence.
l.8 {Worthey}, G. 1994, \apjs
                         , 95, 107
/tmp/.LatexEssay.tex.bbl:8:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output   PDF          file    produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/.LatexEssay.tex.log.
```

My Bibtex file is:

```
    @Article{Narendra_1990,
    author =       {K.S.Narendra and K.Parthsarathy},
    title =        {Identification and Control of Dynamical System
                  using Neural Networks},
    journal =      "IEENN",
    year =         {1990},
    volume =    {1},
    number =    {1},
    month =     {},
    pages =     {4-27},
    note =      {},
    annote =    {}
    @BOOK{texbook,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title= "The {{\TeX}book}",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    year = 1984
    }
    @ARTICLE{1994ApJS...95..107W,
    author = {{Worthey}, G.},
    title = "{Comprehensive stellar population models and the disentanglement  of age and metallicity effects}",
   journal = {\apjs},
   year =  1994,
   month = nov,
   volume = 95,
   pages = {107-149},
   doi = {10.1086/192096},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994ApJS...95..107W},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

If I cite the `texbook` and `Narendra_1990` references I have no problem. It is only when I include the `1994ApJS...95..107W` reference that the error occurs.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in the given error message

```
/tmp/.LatexEssay.tex.bbl:8: Undefined control sequence.
l.8 {Worthey}, G. 1994, \apjs
                         , 95, 107
```

you have an undefined control sequence `\apjs` that causes the error. I guess it should contain the name of a journal. So add the line `@string {apjs  = {The correct name of the journal}}` (add the correct name please) to your `bib` file. With a little pretty printing it could look like this:

```
@string {apjs  = {The correct name of the journal}}
@ARTICLE{1994ApJS...95..107W,
  author  = {{Worthey}, G.},
  title   = {{Comprehensive stellar population models and the disentanglement 
    of age and metallicity effects}},
  journal = apjs,
  year    = {1994},
  month   = nov,
  volume  = {95},
  pages   = {107--149},
  doi     = {10.1086/192096},
  adsurl  = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1994ApJS...95..107W},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
}
```

Did you recognised the `--` in field `pages`?

Comment: Sorry hit the enter button too early:   How do I refer to the apj-jours.bib file that I believe should take care of this problem: '\bibliography{apj-jours,Bib2}' results in no bibliography file detected.  thanks

Comment: Ok, no problem. thanks again for your help. Will accept and upvote.

Comment: From the astronat package: http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/astronat/doc/html/astronat_3.html          I was trying to load two .bib files: apj-jour.bib and my Bib2.bib file.  Further reading seems to indicate that Gummi has  trouble loading two .bib files at the same time so that may be the problem